# how to make a primary key a foreign key in another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

These are my tables. I have a problem with the last one (`Inscription`) it doesn't accept `CodeProjet` as a foreign key. The error says table (`Projet`) doesn't have a primary key called `CodeProjet` but it does! I have used every trick that I know and nothing. I altered the table to add constraint, etc. Still nothing. I always get the same error. Here are the tables:

```
create database Gestion_Stages_Employe

create table Employe
 (
    NumEmploye int primary key,
    NomEmploye varchar(15),
    PrenomEmploye varchar(15),
    SexeEmploye varchar(10),
    DNaissEmploye date,
    FonctionEmploye varchar(20)
  )
  
create table TypeProjet
  (
    TypeProjet varchar(20) primary key,
    libelleProjet varchar(20),
    DureeProjet date,
  )
  
create table Projet
  (
    CodeProjet int,
    TypeProjet varchar(20),
    DateDebut Date, 
    DateFin Date,
    Constraint Pk_CodeProj primary key (CodeProjet,TypeProjet),
    Constraint FK_TypeProj foreign key (TypeProjet) references TypeProjet(TypeProjet),
)

create table Inscription
(
    NumEmploye int foreign key references Employe(NumEmploye),
    CodeProjet int foreign key references Projet(CodeProjet),
    dateiscription Date,
    primary key (NumEmploye,CodeProjet),
)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the primary key on `Projet` is segmented (`CodeProjet, TypeProjet`).

Comment: (Inscription) has two pripary keys, the problem is that is doesn't take "CodeProjet) as a primary key from (Projet) table !! and i did some tests with other databases and work fine, but here i don't understand why :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment, the Primary Key on the Projet table is a "composite key" (multiple columns are required to enforce uniqueness).

As a result, for your foreign key to work, you need to either remove "TypeProjet" from the primary key of Project (assuming CodeProjet is sufficient to uniquely identify a Projet), or you need to add TypeProjet to the Inscription table and define your foreign key with both columns, for example:

```
create table Inscription ( 
  NumEmploye int foreign key references Employe(NumEmploye), 
  CodeProjet int,
  dateiscription Date, 
  TypeProjet varchar(20),
  Constraint fk_Inscription_project Foreign key (CodeProjet,TypeProjet) references Projet(CodeProjet,TypeProjet),
  primary key (NumEmploye,CodeProjet),
)
```

Comment: the exercise required a composite key, yet i thought it was a mistake because it didn't work when i wrote my code above (i'm only talking about this one) and i thought about one key should be sufficient, and when i saw your advice i went with it :) i modified sometings on my winforms for this to work.your code works fine too but i don't want to add new attributes to my table.now i can continue my work thank you @lheria